# Update SQL table using SharePoint Event Receiver while editing a SharePoint list item value

Tags: item-updating

I have a SharePoint list which contains look-up values for visual web part dropdownlist. The records are saved in SQL tables. Now, I want to update all records containing a look-up value  in the SQL table when a look up value in the SharePoint list is updated.

Also, I want to display a message to the users letting them know about the number of rows that will be updated in the SQL table too when a look up value is edited.

Not sure how to achieve this functionality.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a item-updated event receiver, it will be really hard to show a user a message box in item receivers but you can easily navigate them to another page to provide them information they need.

Check this blog post of mine which is for item-adding but you can change it to item-updated by just changing  `public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)` to  `public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)`

http://sharepointbulletin.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/adding-details-to-database-table-using.html

You will also need a new stored procedure for updating database table values.

Check this article for redirecting user to another page (you might be able to display a message box easily in SharePoint 2010 but in SharePoint 2007 this is normally used),

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/4224/sharepoint-2010-event-handler-redirection-to-custom-error-pa.aspx